# Should I inflate the layout in onCreateView or onViewCreated?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, viewmodel

I am using the following fragment to show an onboarding screen on the first launch of the application. Should I inflate my layout in onCreateView or in onViewCreated? I don't quite understand how to decide on this. Also, do I need to create a ViewModel for my code?

```
class OnBoardingFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager
    private lateinit var dotsLayout: LinearLayout
    private lateinit var sliderAdapter: SliderAdapter
    private lateinit var dots: Array<TextView?>
    private lateinit var letsGetStarted: Button
    private lateinit var next: Button
    private lateinit var animation: Animation
    private var currentPos: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.onBoardingFragment, true).build()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_onboarding, container, false)

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.slider);
        dotsLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.dots);
        letsGetStarted = view.findViewById(R.id.get_started_btn);
        next = view.findViewById(R.id.next_btn)

        sliderAdapter = SliderAdapter(requireContext())
        viewPager.adapter = sliderAdapter;

        addDots(0);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(changeListener);

        next.setOnClickListener {
            viewPager.currentItem = currentPos + 1
        }
        letsGetStarted.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_onBoardingFragment_to_loginFragment)
        }
    }

    private fun addDots(position: Int) {
        dots = arrayOfNulls(2)
        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();

        for (i in dots.indices) {
            dots[i] = TextView(requireContext())
            dots[i]!!.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml("&#8226;", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
            dots[i]!!.setTextColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    requireContext(),
                    android.R.color.darker_gray
                )
            )
            dots[i]!!.textSize = 35F
            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i])
        }
        if (dots.isNotEmpty()) {
            dots[position]!!.setTextColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    requireContext(),
                    R.color.wine_red
                )
            )
        }
    }

    private var changeListener: ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener =
        object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int
            ) {
            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                addDots(position)
                currentPos = position
                animation =
                    AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in)
                if (position == 0) {
                    letsGetStarted.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    next.animation = animation
                    next.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    letsGetStarted.animation = animation
                    letsGetStarted.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    next.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
            }

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}
        }

}`
```

Comment: If your intention is to inflate a layout file, instead of creating this barebone `onCreateView` you can use fragments constructor that takes resource id: `class OnBoardingFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_onboarding)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android framework calls Fragment's `onCreateView` to create the view object hierarchy. Therefore, it's correct to inflate the layout here as you did.

`onViewCreated` is called afterwards, usually you find views and setup them. So, your code is ok.

Regarding the ViewModel, in your sample code you're just configuring the UI so you won't need it. If instead, you need to obtain some data from an API service, transform it, show the states of "loading data", "data retrieved" and "there was an error retrieving data", then you would like not to do those things in the fragment and you could consider using an MVVM approach.

Some references:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#fragment_created_and_view_initialized
- https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments
- https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture

Comment: I am very grateful for the time and knowledge you have shared. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateView` is where you inflate the view hierarchy, and return it (so the `Fragment` can display it). If you're handling that inflation yourself, you need to override `onCreateView` so you can take care of it when the system makes that request. That's why it's named that way - *when the view (displayed layout) is being created, this function is called, and it provides a `View`*.

`onViewCreated` is called **after** the `Fragment`'s view has already been created and provided to it for display. You get a reference to that `view` passed in, so you can do setup stuff like assigning click listeners, observing View Models that update UI elements, etc. **You don't inflate your layout here** because it won't be displayed (unless you're explicitly inflating other stuff and adding it to the existing `view` for some reason, which is more advanced and probably not what you're talking about).

So `onCreateView` is really concerned with *creating a view hierarchy for display*, and `onViewCreated` is for taking that displayed hierarchy and *initialising your stuff*. You might not need to implement `onCreateView` at all (e.g. if you use the `Fragment` constructor that takes a layout ID, so it sets it up for you) in which case you'd just implement `onViewCreated` instead. Or if you *are* handling it yourself in `onCreateView`, and you don't have much setup code, you might run that on the `View` you've inflated before you return it, and not bother with `onViewCreated` at all.

It's worth getting familiar with [the Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle) if you haven't already, just so you know the basic way the system moves between states and the callbacks it calls as it does so (and have a look at the documentation for the callback methods too!)